# Howto detect a fail of dynamic memory allocation when pushing to std::deque?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation, stddeque

I am looking for a technique to detect if it is possible or not to push/insert/etc. further elements to a std::deque. It should do dynamic memory allocation for me, but what happens when my memory is full? By using malloc() I would receive a Nullpointer but how to detect a out of memory situation when using a std::deque?

Comment: If you run out of memory you have bigger problems.  If you are running on a limited memory platform (eg embedded), this should be a design issue.

Comment: @RichardCritten: It is an limited embedded platform and I am building a databuffer with specialized buffer-overrun-technqieues (think of filtering entries). Running in out of mem should normally not happen because I introduce a max_buffer_size. But if max_buffer_size is reached OR system is out of memory, I want to detect it to "filter" my buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling out-of-memory situations within standard containers is delegated to the underlying allocator (the second, often not specified template parameter of `std::deque`). If you go with the default `std::allocator`, which throws upon failure in [`std::allocator::allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate), you can wrap the insertion into a try-catch block:

```
try {
   myDeque.push_back(42);
} catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Allocations by the [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) are handled by their allocator, which defaults to [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

The `std::allocator` [`allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) function is using [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) for the allocation.

And `operator new` throws the [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception if it fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Some programmer dude!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

For example, for [`std::deque::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) we read:

> If an exception is thrown (which can be due to Allocator::allocate() or element copy/move constructor/assignment), this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).

Assuming your type doesn't throw on copy/move operations, the only possible place to throw is allocator.

[`std::allocator::allocate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) will throw `std::bad_alloc` on failure:

> Throws std::bad_alloc if allocation fails.